# Input does not pass validation test for strlen

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement

I am making a login system and I have a form with some validation.

However my form seems to be failing to pass the validation even though the data input should pass easily.

See:
http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/index.php

When you input a username, it should be over 3 characters. But even if you enter one really long you get the error message: The username is less than 3 characters.

**EDIT: There was an issue in my copying from formatting that caused a missing }. I've corrected this. It wasn't the issue.**

This is the if statement for the username pass. So it seems like it is not getting past the first test:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'] = $username;
    if(strlen($username) > 3){
        if(strlen($username) < 31){
            if(user_exists($username) === true){
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'That username is already taken. Sorry, please try again with a different username.';
                }else{
                    // passed
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is greater than 30 characters.';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is less than 3 characters.';
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is not entered.';
    }
```

And this is the HTML for the username:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
                <div class="username">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputUser">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="inputUser" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $usern_value; ?>" />
                </div>
```

You can see the site here: http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/index.php

**Session**

The index page does use sessions.

It starts with this:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>
```

And kills the session at the end of the file:

```
<?php 
unset($_SESSION['status']); 
?>
```

But in the file it starts new sessions which store the inputs. This is so if you make a mistake, it still holds your info so you can adjust it rather than having the fill in the form again. Here is an example of where it grabs the username and saves it, then outputs it.

```
<?php 
                        if(isset($_SESSION['status']['register']['username'])){
                                $usern_value = $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'];
                        } else {
                            $usern_value = "";
                        }
                    ?>

value="<?php echo $usern_value; ?>" />
```

This is the `user-exists` function:

```
function user_exists($username){
        $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($result == 1){
            // username does already exist
            return true;
        }else{
            // username doesn't exist in the database
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, the `// passed` else has no corresponding `if`.

Comment: I'd change `if (isset($_POST['username'])){` to `if ($_POST) {`, since you want this check to run in a post op regardless of what fields are available. Then, temporarily, add in this on the next line: `echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>"; exit();`. That will dump what PHP received in the post operation.

Comment: @halfer done but I am not sure what the results mean IRT the problem. SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'marmit_1'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Is this meaning my PDO connection isn't working?

Comment: That looks like an additional problem - your database is not connecting properly, yes. Is this perhaps called from within `user_exists`?

Comment: I don't know. I can't see where. Added `user-exists` to OP.

Comment: The problem will be with your `mysql_connect`, which may be in an initialisation routine somewhere. Incidentally, I would move the `mysql_real_escape_string` to inside the `user_exists` function, otherwise if you call this function from elsewhere, and forget to use the escape function, you'll have a SQL injection vulnerability. This is not your immediate problem, but worth fixing.

Comment: @halfer so you think this is an issue with the PDO? Like an incorrect password? I can see that being true but I don't understand why an issue with my connection script causes a variable to fail a basic if statement.

Comment: Hmm... that is interesting. I should have noticed: the error you report above is from PDO, but all the database code you have shown thus far does not use PDO at all - it is a different way of connecting to the database. So, yes, the connection is a problem (e.g. wrong username or password), but so is (apparently) using two conflicting libraries to connect to the database. You'll need to add debug statements to see where exactly that error is coming from.

Comment: The connection isn't in the code above. I have it stored in a connect.php file which is called into my register function. But at least if I know that is where the problem is I can't start there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I can see the problem from your website link. When the error pops up ("The username is less than 3 characters."), try refreshing your browser. I expected to receive a browser warning that says the data would be resubmitted to the server — because you are in a `post` form — but I did not.

So, what does this mean? It means that immediately after validation failure, you are redirecting back to the same screen, and — unless you are using a session to preserve this information — your `$_POST` data will be lost. Commonly in the case of validation failure with this sort of form, you must prevent that redirect and render inside the post operation, which keeps the user's input available to you. The redirect should only occur if the form input was successful (i.e. it saves to the data and/or sends an email).

Edit: I should have seen the `$_SESSION` in the original post. OK, so the strategy is to write things to the session, redirect regardless of validation outcome, and to save error messages to the session. I wonder whether you are not resetting the session errors array when you're posting the form? Immediately after your first `if`, try adding this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'] = array(); // New line
```

Unless you have something to make the session forget your errors, they will be stored until you delete your browser's cookie.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you mean. But can you explain how to go about fixing the code? This has been working just fine for a while. Also, it uses sessions. I'll add the details to the OP gimme a sec.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a  closing brace `}` on this line:

```
  if(user_exists($username) === true){

         } else{// **missed the closing brace before the else**    
                    // passed
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is your logic so complex?

```
if (strlen($username) < 3) {
    // too short
} elseif (strlen($username) > 31) {
    // too long
} elseif (true === user_exists($username)) {
    // already registered
} else {
    // passed
}
```

Comment: It was written from a tutorial, so I do agree it's complex but was concerned about re-writing it and breaking it.

Comment: I tried changing to your code. It just sent you to a blank page. Even when it should have posted you back with errors. So not ideal.

Comment: The code's valid php, if it doesn't work that would be down to your implementation of it. A blank screen is an indication php errored out, perhaps try turning on error_reporting and display_errors so you can see what the problem actually was.